# Quartz Core CATransaction Flush Consuming lot of memory

Tags: ios, memory-management, instruments, quartz-core, xcode-instruments

I am profiling my application for memory optimisation. I am using ARC. As I use the app the memory used by the [CATransaction flush] of quartz core is increasing. Please find the attached screen shot. How can I optimize it?

[image]

Thanks.